# How to update Angular Router navigation extras without routing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have two components, Inside my first component I have a reactive form. After submission of the form I am using `router.navigate([])` to navigate to the second component. When navigating from first component I am setting an object in Angular Router navigation like this -

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
        name: formvalue.name,
        email: formValue.email
    }
};
this._router.navigate(['/url'], navigationExtras);
```

In my second component I have another form. After submission of the form I am trying to update the email inside router state object. Is there any way to update the state object without routing. I have tried this approach. With this approach the `http://localhost:4200` tab becomes white.

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
       ...this.routeState,
       email: formValue.email
    }

};
this._router.navigate([], navigationExtras);
```

**Question** is there any way to update the router state object without Routing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using queryparams, to have a stateless navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You can for example change the URL params without routing using the `Location` service with `replaceState` like this:

```
constructor(
    private _location: Location,
) {}

...

updateURLWithNewParamsWithoutReloading() {
    const params = new HttpParams().appendAll({
        price: 100,
        product: 'bag'
    });

    this._location.replaceState(
        location.pathname,
        params.toString()
    );
}
```